# SignalR: /signalr/abort throws error

Tags: jquery, signalr, owin

`Refused to execute script from '.../signalr/abort?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&callback=jQuery32109752453231046265_1507885522267&_=1507885522271' because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

A part of url was removed for clarity.

I have the last stable version of `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb` (3.1.0) and `jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js`. I'm using CORS.

`/signalr/start` is working just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: as it's sayin you have to pass a [MIME-TYPE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_type) with your request

Comment: @FelixD. Yeah, but how can I do this? As I can see in source - it should be working without any tuning. No? How can I do that?

Comment: Sadly I ain't no expert. But I'm pretty sure u either need to pass the mime type or change your server => `strict MIME type checking is enabled` (which causes your error since you did no pass a mime type).

Comment: AFAICT the browser refused to execute script returned by `signalr/abort` but... `signalr/abort` does not return any script - it just returns an empty response. I would start from checking what `abort` returned...

Comment: Did you figure out a solution @Kindzoku

Comment: @SachinKainth nope...