# Javascript SignalR Stop Refused to execute script

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr

I'm getting this error when calling **$.connection.hub.stop();**

***Refused to execute script from ... because its MIME type ('') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.***

SignalR Client: **jquery.signalR-2.2.3.min.js**

SignalR Server: **All Nugets are up to date**

**Startup.cs**

```
 app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var Configuration = new HubConfiguration
            {                    
                EnableJSONP = true,
                EnableJavaScriptProxies = true,
                EnableDetailedErrors = true                    
            };
            map.RunSignalR(Configuration);
        });
```

**Javascript**

```
$.connection.hub.start({ jsonp: true }).done(function () { ... });
```

Any ideas about fix?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726457/signalr-signalr-abort-throws-error (i think its the same). Do you need really Enable this JSONP?

Comment: I do, cause I work with cordova project and SignalR does not work in browser at all without JSONP enabled

Comment: We seem to be having this issue too :(

Comment: I know it is late. I am getting this issue seldom. Did anyone have solution for this issue ?

Comment: In my case I did a workaround, instead of fix. In case of Apache Cordova project, all you have to do is Visual Studio -> Options -> Tools For Apache Cordova -> Plugin Simulation -> Uncheck Enable XHR proxying. After that you don't need JSONP and whole configuration object in SignalR